# Creating a bouncing box animation on canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create an animation of dropping box, which supposed to bounce 10 times when it reaches a certain Y point on canvas, each time twice lower that the previous. So I have the animation of the dropping box, but I can't make the bounce work. Here are the functions that I wrote:

```
function dropBox(y, width, height) {
    var img_box = new Image();
    img_box.src = 'images/gift_box_small.png';

    var box_y_pos = y;
    if(y==0)
        box_y_pos = y-img_box.naturalHeight;


    img_box.onload = function(){
        ctx_overlay.save();
        ctx_overlay.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
        ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (width/2)-(img_box.naturalWidth/2), box_y_pos);
        ctx_overlay.restore();
    }

    box_y_pos += 3;

    var box_bottom_position = box_y_pos - img_box.naturalHeight;

    if(box_y_pos+img_box.naturalHeight<height-25)
        var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {dropBox(box_y_pos, width, height)},24);
    else
        bounceBox(img_box, box_y_pos, box_y_pos, (height/2)-(img_box.naturalHeight/2), "up");

}

function bounceBox(img, img_final_pos, y, midway_pos, direction){
    var midway = midway_pos;
    var direction = direction;
    var img_y_pos = y;

    img.onload = function(){
        ctx_overlay.save();
        ctx_overlay.clearRect(0,0,docWidth,docHeight);
        ctx_overlay.drawImage(img, (docWidth/2)-(img.naturalWidth/2), img_y_pos);
        ctx_overlay.restore();
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(direction=="up"){
            //going up
            if(img_y_pos>midway_){
                img_y_pos -= 3;
                var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {bounceBox(img, img_final_pos, img_y_pos, midway_pos, "up")},24);
            } else {
                img_y_pos += 3;
                midway = Math.floor(midway /= 2);
                if(midway%2>0)
                    midway += 1;
                var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {bounceBox(img, img_final_pos, img_y_pos, midway_pos, "down")},24);
            }
        } else {
            //going down
            if(img_y_pos < img_final_pos){
                img_y_pos += 3;
                var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {bounceBox(img, img_final_pos, img_y_pos, midway_pos, "down")},24);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2derqgw/3/

Why isn't it working and how can I make it work?

Comment: Here's some pseudo-code to get you pointed in the right direction. `if(Box_Y + Box_VY >= canvas_height) Box_VY*=-1;` Basically what that would do (not using your variables) is if the position the box is going to be in is greater than the height of the canvas, reverse the direction of the box. When I do animation I have a single `setInterval()` that calls a singular draw function with separate function calls within the draw function (just for cleanliness). When drawing a shape I usually have a velocity variable and a position variable. For example: `Box_VY`. If Box_VY is - than Y is going down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid getting a headache, you've better handle the animation within a single function called with a setInterval.
And keep all animation-related data in one object.
So the code below does not exactly what you want, but should get you started :

http://jsfiddle.net/n2derqgw/4/

Setup :

```
var canvas_overlay, ctx_overlay, docWidth, docHeight;

var img_box = new Image();
img_box.src = 'http://corkeynet.com/test/images/gift_box_small.png';

var mustBeReadyCount = 2; // must load image and window

img_box.onload = launchWhenReady;
window.onload = launchWhenReady;

var animationStep = '';
var boxAnimationData = {
    animationStep: '',
    y: 0,
    maxY: 0,
    bounceCount: 6,
    direction: -1,
    bounceHeight: 0
};

function launchWhenReady() {
    mustBeReadyCount--;
    if (mustBeReadyCount) return;
    docWidth = window.innerWidth;
    docHeight = window.innerHeight;
    canvas_overlay = document.getElementById('canvas_overlay');
    ctx_overlay = canvas_overlay.getContext('2d');
    resizeCanvas(docWidth, docHeight);
    boxAnimationData.animationStep = 'falling';
    boxAnimationData.bounceHeight = docHeight / 2 - img_box.height;
    setInterval(animateBox, 30);
};
```

More interesting code is here :

```
function animateBox() {
    if (boxAnimationData.animationStep == 'falling') dropBox();
    else if (boxAnimationData.animationStep == 'bouncing') bounceBox();
}

function dropBox() {
    ctx_overlay.clearRect(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);
    boxAnimationData.y += 3;
    if (boxAnimationData.y + img_box.height > docHeight) {
        boxAnimationData.animationStep = 'bouncing';
    }
    ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (docWidth / 2) - (img_box.width / 2), boxAnimationData.y);
}


function bounceBox() {
    ctx_overlay.clearRect(0, 0, docWidth, docHeight);
    boxAnimationData.y += boxAnimationData.direction * 3;
    if (boxAnimationData.y + img_box.height > docHeight) {
        // reached floor ? swap direction
        boxAnimationData.direction *= -1;
        //  and reduce jump height
        boxAnimationData.bounceHeight *= 3 / 2;
        boxAnimationData.bounceCount--;
        if (!boxAnimationData.bounceCount) boxAnimationData.animationStep = '';

    } else if (boxAnimationData.y < boxAnimationData.bounceHeight) {
        boxAnimationData.direction *= -1;
    }
    ctx_overlay.drawImage(img_box, (docWidth / 2) - (img_box.width / 2), boxAnimationData.y);
}
```

Comment: Actually it's exactly what I wanted! Just changed a few parameters and it worked just fine. The problem now is when I try to combine it with other animation I have on page: I see the other animation, but I don't see the box: http://jsfiddle.net/n2derqgw/6/ What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well a very good way of doing things is to settle once and for all the issue of the loading : load *all* the images you need, then launch your application. If you do this, i'll have a look to your code. Cheers